# Geotools Quickstart tutorial JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile is causing error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, geotools

I was looking at the Geotools Quickstart tutorial using Eclipse
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html
I followed all the steps and it all went well until I ran the Quickstart class

When I run the Quickstart class. I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath(Win32ShellFolder2.java:571)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$400(Win32ShellFolder2.java:72)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$2.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:298)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$2.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:296)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And I found out that this method is causing the problem JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile

I commented out all the other lines except for the one using the method above, and still got the same error. (there is no error if I commented that line as well)

```
package org.geotools.tutorial;

import java.io.File;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.SLD;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;

/**
 * Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays the contents on the screen in a map frame.
 * <p>
 * This is the GeoTools Quickstart application used in documentationa and tutorials. *
 */
public class Quickstart {

    /**
     * GeoTools Quickstart demo application. Prompts the user for a shapefile and displays its
     * contents on the screen in a map frame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // display a data store file chooser dialog for shapefiles
          /*********This is the line *********/
          File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
          /***********************************/

//        if (file == null) {
//            return;
//        }
//
//        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
//        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
//
//        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
//        MapContent map = new MapContent();
//        map.setTitle("Quickstart");
//        
//        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
//        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
//        map.addLayer(layer);
//
//        // Now display the map
//        JMapFrame.showMap(map);
    }

}
```

Also, in pom.xml, I tried versions 8.0-M2 and 8-SNAPSHOT. but no luck...

Anyone has any ideas?
Is there something wrong with module geotools.swing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is a bug with `sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath` method that triggers the NPE.

One suggests to use JDK 1.6.0u21 or above to solve it.

Check on Google with keywords `"NullPointerException sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried google that keywords. In http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=186615, it said it's fixed in 6u21, in http://www.dbvis.com/forum/message.jspa?messageID=10866, it said revert back to version 6u18. I tried both, still got the NullPointerException but different stacktrace. My original version is JDK 7

Answer (score 1):

I have been also trying the Geotools Quickstart tutorial and I had the same problem.

I finally add:

`import org.geotools.data.shapefile.*;`

and change

`FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);`

by

`ShapefileDataStore store = new ShapefileDataStore(file.toURI().toURL());`

It doesn't solve the question of the exception but it can be an alternative.